# Migrating security certificate from IIS 6.0 to IIS 7.0

Tags: iis-7, ssl, certificate

We have a security certificate configured in IIS 6.0 on our old server. We are migrating to a new server. How do I migrate the security certificate of our website from IIS 6.0 to IIS 7.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to export the certificate to a pfx file (go through the certificate wizard, and export should be one of the options).  Them import this certificate into IIS 7 on the Windows 2008 machine.

Answer (score 0):

The Certificates snap-in isn't in Administrative Tools like you may assume.  From your Run prompt type "MMC" then add a snap-in for Certificates.  You'll likely find your certificate under "Personal".  Export that that and import it to IIS7.  In IIS7 you can do the import at the top level of IIS.  You don't need to use the Certificates snap-in.

Comment: Why not just use the IIS Management Console to export the certificate?

Comment: You can do that too.  I tend to do it in the MMC snap-in directly, but IIS Manager can do an export well too.  Both will accomplish the same for a simple export.

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.sslshopper.com/move-or-copy-an-ssl-certificate-from-a-windows-server-to-another-windows-server.html